# Would optional static typing benefit Python API-design or be a disadvantage? (type checking decorator example included)

Tags: python, static-typing

I'm a long time Python developer and I really love the dynamic nature of the language, but I wonder if Python would benefit from optional static typing.
**Would it be beneficial to be able to apply static typing to the API of a library, and what would the disadvantages of this be?**

I quickly sketched up a decorator implementing runtime-static type checking [on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/aY20mgGr) and it works like this:

```
# A TypeError will be thrown if the argument "string" is not a "str" and if 
# the returned value is not an "int"
@typed(int, string = str)
def getStringLength(string):
    return len(string)
```

Would it be practical to use a decorator like this on the API-functions of a library? In my point of view type checking is not needed in the internal workings of a domain specific module of a library, but on the connection points between the library and it's client a simple version of design by contract by applying type checking could be useful. Especially as a type of enforced documentation which clearly states to the client of the library what it expects and returns.

Like this example where `addObjectToQueue()` and `isObjectProcessed()` are exposed for use by the client and `processTheQueueAndDoAdvancedStuff()` is an internal library function. I think type checking could be useful on the outward facing functions but would only bloat and restrict the dynamicness and usefulness of python if used on the internal functions.

```
# some_library_module.py

@typed(int, name = string)
def addObjectToQueue(name):
    return random.randint() # Some object id

def processTheQueueAndDoAdvancedStuff(arg_of_library_specific_type)
    # Function body here

@typed(bool, object_id = int)
def isObjectProcessed(object_id):
    return True
```

**What would the disadvantages of using this technique be?
What would the disadvantages of my naive implementation [on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/aY20mgGr) be?**

I don't want answers discussing the conversion of Python to a statically typed language, but thoughts about API design-specific pros/cons. (please move this to programmers.stackexchange.com if you consider it not a question)

Comment: `What would the disadvantages of using this technique be?` Loss of duck typing.

Answer (score 8):

Personally, I don't find this idea attractive for Python. This is all just my opinion, of course, but for context I'll tell you that Python and Haskell are probably my two favourite programming languages - I like languages at both extreme ends of the static vs dynamic typing spectrum.

I see the main benefits of static typing as follows:

1. Increased likelihood that your code is correct once the compiler has accepted it; if I know I've threaded my values through all the operations I invoked in such a way that the result type of one always matches the input type of another, and the final result type is the one I wanted, it increases the probability that I've selected the *correct* operations. This point is of deeply arguable value, since it only really matters if you're not testing very much, which would be bad. But it is true that, when programming in Haskell, when I sit back and say "there, done!" I am actually done a lot of the time, whereas that's almost never true of my Python code.
2. The compiler automatically points out most of the places that need changing when I make an incompatible change to a data structure or interface (most of the time). Again, tests are still needed to actually be sure you've caught all the implications, but most of the time the compiler's nagging is actually sufficient, in my experience, which deeply simplifies such refactoring; you can go straight from implementing the core of the refactoring to testing that the program still works okay, because the actual work of making all the flow-on changes is almost mechanical.
3. Efficient implementation. The compiler gets to use all the knowledge it has about types to do optimisation.

Your suggested system doesn't really provide any of these benefits.

1. Having written a program making use of your library, I still don't know if it contains any type-incorrect uses of your functions until I do extensive testing with full code coverage to see if any execution path contains a bad call.
2. When I refactor something, I need to go through many many rounds of "run full test suite, look for exception, find where it came from, fix the code" to get anything at all like a static-typing compiler's problem detection.
3. Python will still be behaving as if those variables could be anything at any time.

And to get even that much, you've sacrificed the flexibility of Python duck-typing; it's not enough that I provide a sufficiently "list-like" object, I have to actually provide a list.

To me, this sort of static typing is the worst of both worlds. The main dynamic typing argument is "you have to test your code anyway, so you may as well use those tests to catch type errors and free yourself from having to work around the type system when it doesn't help you". That may or may not be a good argument with respect to a really good static type system, but it **absolutely** is a compelling argument with respect to a weak partial static type system that only detects type errors at runtime. I don't think nicer error messages (which is all it really buys you most of the time; a type error not caught at the interface is almost certainly going to throw an exception deeper in the call stack) is worth the loss of flexibility.